# Create API Gateway request model for non JSON content type

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I have built several REST API endpoints fronted by AWS API Gateway which accept and return JSON. I have defined request models for these endpoints so that the the documentation can be exported and imported into Swagger for testing. This all works well.

However one endpoint accepts a custom type (it's text but in a custom structure), not JSON, and I can't figure out how to define a request model for something that isn't JSON. The model must be written in [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) and all of the AWS documentation examples only demonstrate JSON requests and responses (examples listed at the end).

For example the following request model:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "File Upload Request",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "filename": {
      "description": "Filename of the file being uploaded (with extension)",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

renders like this in Swagger:

[image: Swagger request body]

An empty text area would be acceptable, although it would be great if I could add sample input. Is this possible?

---

Examples from AWS documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-photos.html#example-photos-input-mapping
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-news-article.html#example-news-article-input-model
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-invoice.html#example-invoice-input-model
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-employee.html#example-employee-input-model

Comment: As of me answering this question, you can only define a model for a JSON document. If you're using XML or something else, you're out of luck.